# Jerky boat motion, how can I smooth this out?

Tags: animation

I followed these two methods to animate a large yacht hull:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smArCTzxGpE

&

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfi7HW8qHAo

I'd like to mention that I am a Blender newbie and that I have not finetuned materials, environment and the amount of foam generated in my file.
Basically my ship is guided along a curve with the help of an underwater slider plane.

Here is what I got so far:

https://youtu.be/W1eDkpwtL8U

Unfortunately this is way to fast in boat movements (not boat speed) for a large yacht.
A large yacht would usually not have the transom exit the water that far.
What can I do about this?

I tried already to reduce the rotation around the horizontal axis in the hope that would smooth the motion out. 
Please have a look for this on the attached screenshot of my setup.

Or is it more of a scaling issue between ocean and yacht?

This is closer to where I want to go:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtoG8jPQEyE

But I'd like to use a slightly(!) less slick ocean.

A last question, this:

https://youtu.be/zlIVtofxY-I

has a nice wave distribution along the hull (=bow wave, followed by through and stern wave) What is the method to achieve this? I did not understand that from the description given.

Is it the shape of the plane which slides along the pathcurve? Do I need a modifier on it?

Thanks up front for your input!

Comment: Drop us your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Uups Lukasz, just saw your reply. I had missed it before.
Thank you for offering that, but I am not able to share the actual file due to copyright issues.

Still, I got it to work a fair bit.
Now there are more questions arising. Maybe someone can help on the base of the current result:

Comment: https://youtu.be/2kjzzCOgbDU

Comment: Current questions are:

1)WAKE
How can I have the wake fade out gently, rather than sudden as seen in youtube?
Looks also like its stretching and suddenly does snap more towards the boat like a rubberband. I suspect this is due to the tiled ocean surface.

2)WAVE ALONG HULL
I like to deform the bowwave and also show the through forming along the hull when the boat is moving. 
Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: 3)SEASURFACE
I am working in mm units throughout and do not want to change this. Still I want to achieve a less slick sea surface with more and smaller waves. Any idea how this could be done?
I tried already more chopyness, but that does not help.

4)PICTURES
How can I attach some screenshot in this thread?

Thanks for any help.